# What is a "character short name" in ISO/IE 10646?

Tags: c++, unicode, c++11

C++11 2.3/2 says:

> The character designated by the universal-character-name \UNNNNNNNN is
>   that character whose character short name in ISO/IEC 10646 is NNNNNNNN

So I downloaded [ISO/IEC 10646](http://www.iso.org/iso/home/store/catalogue_tc/catalogue_detail.htm?csnumber=56921), but I was unable to find a definition of "character short name." Can somebody please clarify what this is supposed to refer to?

My original goal was to find out why 8 hex digits are required when specifying a code point with \U, given that six digits always suffice.  So I'd also be interested to know why C++11 specifies that we use \UNNNNNNNN instead of \UNNNNNN.

Comment: Lazy implementations will just store the hex value of `\UNNNNNNNN` in the corresponding `char32_t` variable without checking that it is a valid Unicode codepoint. That saves on compiler complexity (and on shipping the entire Unicode database with the compiler), and it's also reasonably future-proof.

Comment: Note, although the ISO webstore apparently offers you the opportunity to donate money (more than US$250!) in return for a download, that page also [links](http://standards.iso.org/ittf/PubliclyAvailableStandards/c056921_ISO_IEC_10646_2012.zip) to a free copy.

Answer (score 6):

In the [Unicode character code charts](http://www.unicode.org/charts/), each character has a full name and a short name. For example the character `/` has the full name `SOLIDUS` and the short name `002F`. Not coincidentally, all of the character short names are representable in hex.

As to why 8 digits must be specified, I suspect that's for forward-compatibility with future versions of the Unicode standard that may use larger/more character blocks.

Comment: UTF16 cannot hold more than 0x10FFFF, and (in November 2003) UTF8 was edited to bring the limit _down_ to match that constraint.  But it still may be as you say. http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3629

Comment: @Mooing : For all I know, it was merely to simplify the C++ grammar, since `hex-quad` was already defined. :-P

Answer (score 1):

I'd venture the guess that we got bitten last time by the Unicode guys: C++ initially made `wchar_t` such that it can hold every possibly Unicode character. For this it was required to hold at least 16 bits because Unicode was meant to use at most 16 bits. Shortly after a popular implementation decided to actually use a 16 bit `wchar_t` type it was found that 16 bits actually isn't enough. Last time I looked Unicode used 20 bit but why gamble on being too short again? It is unlikely that there will be widespread use of 24 bit types and if you need to use a specific code point it is most like using only 16 bit, i.e., you can use `\uNNNN`.

The description in 2.3 [lex.charset] paragraph 2 seems to indicate that universal-character-names refers to code points. At the same time, universal-character-name is used to refer to character short name. I'm not an expert for Unicode but I'd think code points are meant.

Comment: The expansion to 20 bits is similar to the IPv6 expansion to 128 bits: sufficient for the foreseeable future. There's a very limited number of languages to start with (~10.000), and most of the obscure languages don't have scripts anyway.